# EXE Setup Installation

Tags: installation, installation-package

Does anyone know an easy to use application that creates exe setup installation package for any windows program? InstallJammer looks a good candidate but its development is discontinued and it does not create a desktop icon although I configured it to do so (probably a bug - googling did not help much). Any comment would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an installer program: read a path to install to, from registry key (something like wix/installshield/nsis)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115832/create-an-installer-program-read-a-path-to-install-to-from-registry-key-somet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All a question of how complicated you want to get. If you just need something quick to install a handful of files, I would recommend NSIS. If you need something with a bit more power and flexibility I'd go with WiX, which emits Windows Installer MSI packages.

Both of these a script\text based, so you can see what you are doing, and don't have any license fees.

Answer (score 0):

I second the recommendation for NSIS.  It will do everything you need, works with XP, Vista and Windows 7.  Is compatible with 64-bit and handles user privileges and short-cuts.

It is all I use for all of my installers and patches and some of them are quite complex, it is also free and open-source.

Download the main framework at http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download and then I would also recommend using the HM-NSIS editor for writing your scripts http://hmne.sourceforge.net/